Design differential equation FOR FIR filter
I need to design a difference equation that will be used as an FIR type filter that will block the frequencies 20 to 40 Hz, and its spectral resolution is Df=0.3 and Dt=2mSec.
I need to write down an analytic expression and I'm not sure how to approach it
NO USING WINDOW
M(Odd Num)=(M-1)/2
your help please
Im not sure about what I wrote.

A difference equation is a linear recursion, or a finite linear filter. A differential equation contains derivatives of a function over a continuous time domain. Time and frequency resolution should give the available filter length, then look at the Fourier transform?

Hf=Hf+(sin(w1*(m-(M-1)/2))./(m-(M-1)/2)/pi...
-sin(w2*(m-(M-1)/2))./(m-(M-1)/2)/pi...
+sin(pi*(m-(M-1)/2))./(m-(M-1)/2)/pi).exp(-iwf*m);
when w1 is 2pi20dt
and w2 is 2pi40dt
is it look fine ?
